# Why does my voltage divider output seem to vary depending on the order of magnitude of overall resistance?

Tags: voltage, resistors, voltage-divider, multimeter

I'm working on a project where I want an Arduino Uno to measure the voltage of a 12V lead acid battery.

The Uno's analogue read pins can't handle raw 12V, so I need to use a voltage divider with roughly a 1/3 stepdown ratio to take the max 14.70 (while charging) down to 5V or less so the pin doesn't fry.

I initially built my divider circuit with R2=503K ohms, and R1 = 1M Ohms, which should give a Vout/Vin ratio of 0.334. I built the circuit and in practice I get a ratio of 0.252 or something like that (battery voltage is 12.97 and the divider is outputting 3.28V, all measured with multimeter.) 0.252 would be fine and safe enough for the Arduino, but I want to get as close to 0.334 as possible to get as much resolution of my battery voltages as the 0-5V of the analogue pin can give me.

I chose the biggest resistors I have because I don't want any more current than absolutely necessary to flow through the divider and get wasted as heat (also makes me nervous as a short circuit risk.) I do realize that this will make the current flow through the divider extremely small, something on the order of 10^-6 Amps. However this seems to be affecting the voltage that's produced.

I wonder if there is some sort of minimum current requirement for a multimeter/analogue pin to read a voltage correctly?

I've double checked the resistor values with the multimeter (within what their specs say they should be with 5% tolerance) and I set up an experiment that demonstrated the weird behaviour I'm seeing.

With R2=R1, I built two different voltage dividers, the first one with two 680K resistors, and the second one with 68K resistors.

The 68K divider gave Vout/Vin of 6.33/12.97=0.488, closer to the theoretical number I should be getting of 0.500.

The 680K divider gave Vout/Vin of 4.85/12.96=0.373.

What gives?

Comment: You may want to use a buffer between your divider and the analog pin. With such high value resistors, any loading, affects the voltage reading significantly.

Comment: @Big6 what sort of buffer?

Comment: A voltage buffer. There are lots of options. See this: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/344476/is-a-buffer-needed-to-measure-the-output-of-a-power-supply-using-an-adc

Comment: If I'm not mistaken the impedance of the external circuit, connected to the ADC, is recommended to be less than 100kOhm. Check the MCU datasheet to be sure.

Comment: @FedeWar does that apply to a multimeter as well? And why does the circuit need to be under 100kOhm?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why high impedance source in ADC input causes error?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/351321/why-high-impedance-source-in-adc-input-causes-error)

Comment: @Alderson give me a bit to read it over, but I think its pretty close

Comment: @Big6, if Im understanding the root of the issue, its basically that once I have a circuit where the order of magnitude of its impedance is on par with what the multimeter or ADC is (ballpark 1 MOhm for multimeter, Im seeing 10-100 MOhm for Arduino ADC), the multimeter starts acting like another big resistor instead of an approximately infinitely resistive path?

Comment: You're correct. And that's why a buffer helps. It presents itself as a low impedance source to the measurement device.

Comment: @BruceJohnJennerLawso If you [read this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/479350/38098), you'll find a lot more detailed discussion about the reasons why you are observing those differences. I think you do qualitatively understand it now, from the discussion here. But it might be nice to see a "made easy" explanation that is drawn out and detailed, as well. You can even calculate the unknown load in your first case with the 1 M Ohm resistor: going from a predicted .334 to an estimated .252 says the unknown measuring load was 1.02 M Ohm.

Comment: _"Im seeing 10-100 MOhm for Arduino ADC"_ - I'm not sure where you're getting those values, but the Atmega328P datasheet mentions that the ADC is optimized for use with a source impedance of <10kΩ. It's quite likely the impedance of your voltage divider is too high.

Comment: Also look at meter resistance. Some have 1 MOhm input R, some 10M, some ... . 1M in parallel with = 500K reduces R by 33%. Even 10M in parallel with 500K reduces R by about 5%. As R reduces error reduces.

Answer (score 0):

The load is also part of the voltage divider.  When you connect your voltmeter it takes some current and in doing so changes the voltage at the junction.

The Arduino will do this too. There should be details of how much in the manual for the Arduino's processor.